# Second element did not appear simultaneously in first debug with first element

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, drop-down-menu

Here is my code. Please kindly help me because I don't have any basic Javascript programming. The second element and button did not appear if user NOT SELECT OTHERS from first drop down list. Then the selection couldn't submit because the button didn't appear. If user select OTHERS from first drop down list, the second element and button will be appear or visible. What is causing this?

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script>
function checkchange() {
    if (document.getElementById('favouritecolour').value == 'OTHERS') {
        document.getElementById('other').style.display='block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('other').style.display='none';
    }
};


function check() {
    if (document.getElementById('pets').value == 'OTHERS') {
       document.getElementById('besides').style.display='block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('besides').style.display='none';
    }
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<select id='favouritecolour' onChange='checkchange()'>
    <option value='BLUE'>BLUE</option>
    <option value='RED'>RED</option>
    <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='other' style="display: none">
    <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN"/><br/>
    <select id='pets' onChange='check()'>
        <option value='DOG'>DOG</option>
        <option value='RABBIT'>RABBIT</option>
        <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='besides' style="display: none">
    <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN"/>
    <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ehm... I don't quite get what is your question? I tried this and it seems to be working?

Comment: it is working. But I want both of drop down and button element appear in the first run or debug the code. It seems visible one by one.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
 <script>
 function checkchange() {
  if(document.getElementById('favouritecolour').value === 'OTHERS') {
    document.getElementById('other').style.display='block';
}else {
    document.getElementById('other').style.display='none';
            document.getElementById('pets').value = "DOG"; // Reset the value to Dog 
            document.getElementById('besides').style.display='none'; // You need to hid this one two this will fix your issue
        }
    };


    function check() {
        if(document.getElementById('pets').value === 'OTHERS') {
            document.getElementById('besides').style.display='block';
        }else{
            document.getElementById('besides').style.display='none';
        }
    };
    </script>
</head>
<body>

    <select id='favouritecolour' onChange='checkchange()'>
        <option value='BLUE'>BLUE</option>
        <option value='RED'>RED</option>
        <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
    </select>
    <div id='other' style="display: none">
        <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN"><br />
        <select id='pets' onChange='check()'>
            <option value='DOG'>DOG</option>
            <option value='RABBIT'>RABBIT</option>
            <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id='besides' style="display: none">
        <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" id="submit"/>
</body>
</html>
```

First of all, close all html tags!
Second, mostly its better to check for "===" instead of "==" in JS (google about why).
Third and finnaly, you need to hide the element

Comment: If that was not the issue ... try to fix that with google ... its just something about if/else statements

Comment: Hmmm. For example, If I choose BLUE. Then how I gonna to submit the what i choose if the submit button did not appear? Hmmmm. Quite confusing and I already try to search the solution, but did not get it.

Comment: How user gonna choose their pet if user select favourite colour either blue or red?

Answer (score 0):

```js
// global variable
var el_other = document.getElementById('other');
var el_favour = document.getElementById('favouritecolour');
var el_pets = document.getElementById('pets');
var el_besides = document.getElementById('besides');

function checkchange() { 
    if (el_favour.value == 'OTHERS') {
        el_other.style.display='block';
    } else {
       
       el_pets.selectedIndex = 0;  // select first option in el_pets (1) 
       check() // call function check()  to re-step (2)
       
       
        el_other.style.display='none';
    }
};


function check() {
    if (el_pets.value == 'OTHERS') {
       el_besides.style.display='block';
    } else {
        el_besides.style.display='none';
    }
};
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<select id='favouritecolour' onChange='checkchange()'>
    <option value='BLUE'>BLUE</option>
    <option value='RED'>RED</option>
    <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='other' style="display: none">
    <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN"/><br/>
    <select id='pets' onChange='check()'>
        <option value='DOG'>DOG</option>
        <option value='RABBIT'>RABBIT</option>
        <option value='OTHERS'>OTHERS</option>
</select>
<div id='besides' style="display: none">
    <input type='text' placeholder="FILL IN"/>
    <input type="submit" name="SUBMIT" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for example : if I select Blue colour for my option. then. How I wanna submit if the submit button did not appear?